Как изменять файлы при работе с удаленным ftp сервером
Есть удаленный ftp-server. На нем развернут действующий сайт. Сайт сверстан с помощью ModX. У меня есть доступ к ftp-серверу (логин пароль). Нужно внести изменения в верстку сайта.
Файловая структура такова:
/
    .cagefs
    .cl.selector
    .cpanel
    .htpasswds
    .jbm
    .softaculous
    .spamassassin
    .ssh
    .trash
    access-logs
    dev.site.com
    site-category.com
    etc
    logs
    movedir
    old_public_html
    perl5
    public_ftp
    public_html
    ssl
    tmp
    www
    

Я никогда не работала с данной CMS, поэтому не могу понять, в какой из директорий необходимо внести изменения. Предполагаю, что внести изменения нужно в dev.site.com. Пробовала скачать данную папку с помощью filezilla, но, в связи с тем, что папка слишком большая, сервер ограничил возможность данную. Обычно я имела дело с git репозиториями, которые клонировала себе на локальный ПК и работала с ним. Но тут я вижу в папках dev.site.com, public_html, что файл .gitignore есть, но при вводе git status (при подключении к ftp серверу через консоль) - пишет, что недопустимая команда. Поэтому меня интересует алгоритм, каким образом мне стоит вносить изменения в код сайта.
Правка 1
Нашла файлы css, внесла изменения — работает. Также нашла chunk с мобильным меню, который нужно изменить. При внесении изменений в верстку — работает.
<nav class="mobile-header__nav">
            <ul class="mobile-header__nav-list">
                {'pdoMenu' | snippet : [
                    'parents' => 0,
                    'level' => 2,
                    'showHidden' => 1,
                    'tvFilters' => 'menuDisplayTop==1',
                    'hereClass' => 'active',
                    'tplOuter' => '@INLINE {$wrapper}',
                    'tpl' => '@INLINE <li class="mobile-header__nav-item {$classnames}">
                                                <a href="{$link}" class="mobile-header__nav-link {$classnames}">{$menutitle}</a>
                                                <span class="arrow">!</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="header__nav-divider"></li>',
                    'tplParentRow' => '@INLINE <li class="mobile-header__nav-item {$classnames}">
                                                        <a href="{$link}" class="mobile-header__nav-link mobile-header__nav-link--show {$classnames}">{$menutitle}</a>
                                                        <span class="arrow">!</span>
                                                        <ul class="mobile-header__submenu">
                                                            {$wrapper}
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="header__nav-divider"></li>',
                    'tplInnerRow' => '@INLINE <li class="mobile-header__submenu-item {$classnames}">
                                                        <a href="{$link}" class="mobile-header__submenu-link {$classnames}">
                                                            {$menutitle}
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>',
                ]}
            </ul>
        </nav>

Каким образом в таком случае можно внести срабатывание функции при нажатии на добавленный элемент (span с !)?

Файловая структура которую Вы привели, относится скорее к хостингу, а не самой CMS как таковой. Так же имейте ввиду, что сами шаблоны в ModX хранятся в базе данных, то есть работать с ними нужно через панель администратора (имеется ввиду разметка), если ничего не поменялось за последние несколько лет.

@Simon, у меня есть доступ к админке сайта. В таком случае, если мне нужно изменить отображение элементов меню в мобильной версии, необходимо все это проводить в админке?

Ну здесь зависит от того, что конкретно нужно изменить) Если саму разметку, то да, если же изменения касаются CSS/JS, то кажется это находится в папке assets/templates/имя_темы, но лучше сверьтесь с документацией ModX той версии которая используется у Вас.
